# Create link in Ruby on Rails to update a specific database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I want to create a very simple application. I used scaffolding to create a database called users. Two of the fields in users are `limit` and `containers`, which is the max number of containers a user can have and the remaining total containers that they can have. They both start off at a given number (e.g. 15), but when a user takes one `containers` will go down to 14 and will continue to decrease every time they take one, until it reaches 0. When a user returns a container, the number for `container` goes up by one until the max number, 15 in my example.

Since I created this using Ruby scaffolding, I can just go to the edit page for each user right now and manually change the `containers` value, but that can allow me to change it to any number. On the `users/:id` page I want to have a link like the edit link that is there right now

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %>
```

and have something similar, but along the lines of

```
<%= link_to 'Take container', #run method to decrease and return here# %>
<%= link_to 'Return container', #run method to increase and return here# %>
```

For now, all I care about is just changing the number and elsewhere I will be rendering the user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX would be a good fit here, but that would complicate the question, so I will stick to doing it with Rails.

You will first need to edit your routes.rb file to include something like:

```
get '/remove_container/:user_id', to: 'users#remove_container', :as => :remove_container
get '/add_container/:user_id', to: 'users#add_container', :as => :add_container
```

Then add methods in your Users controller:

```
def remove_container
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  @user = User.find user_id
  # code to change container number
  redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
end
def add_container
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  @user = User.find user_id
  # code to change container number
  redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
end
```

There are a lot of things to make this better, but this should get you going in the right direction anyway.

Links to these could be made manually or done with paths:

```
<a href="/remove_container/[:user_id]">Remove Container</a>
```

or

```
link_to "Remove Container", remove_container_path(@user)
```

Comment: How do I write the proper link so that it calls these methods?

Comment: link_to(body, url, html_options = {})